# add time greater than 24 hours to datetime in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one datetime field, '2017-05-03 10:00:00' and I want to add the time with field greater than 24 hours, like '30:05' which means 30 hours and 5 minutes in the datetime field. how could I do that? thanks. I'm using sql server 2014.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

To get the hours:minutes to minutes:

```
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, timestr)
```

Where timestr is your 'h:m' string for input.

The result will be minutes.  You should be able to then use this result with [the DATEADD function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql).

```
DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, timestr), dateTimeColumn)
```

So in an UPDATE I'd expect something like:

```
SET dateTimeColumn = DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, timestr), dateTimeColumn)
```